# Sove the wave equation

Tags: wave-equation

Previous exercise

Express

f(t)=\begin{cases}
0,& 0\leqslant t<\pi\\
-\sin t,& \pi\leqslant t\leqslant 2\pi.
\end{cases}
as a full-range Fourier series.
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac 2{2\pi} \int_\pi^{2\pi}-\sin t\cos\left(2\pi t\frac n{2\pi} \right)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi \int_\pi^{2\pi} \sin t\cos nt\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi \left[\frac{n \sin (t) \sin (n t)+\cos (t) \cos (n t)}{n^2-1}\right]_\pi^{2\pi}\\
&= \frac{\cos (2 \pi  n)}{n^2-1} + \frac{\cos (\pi  n)}{n^2-1}, n\geqslant 2
\end{align}

\begin{align} a_n &= \frac {1-(-1)^{n+1}}{(1-n^2)\pi}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
b_n &= \frac 2{2\pi} \int_\pi^{2\pi}-\sin t\sin\left(2\pi t\frac n{2\pi} \right)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\frac{n \sin (t) \cos (n t)-\cos (t) \sin (n t)}{n^2-1}\right]_\pi^{2\pi}\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left(\frac{\sin (2 \pi  n)}{n^2-1} +\frac{\sin (\pi  n)}{n^2-1}\right), n\geqslant 2.
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
b_n &=0\end{align}

I want to solve this equation by using result of the previous exercise 
[image]

I dont know where to start, someone you can help me ?

Comment: So you want to solve 3., ie $u_{xx}=u_{tt}$, Is that correct?

Comment: yes i want solv  u_{xx} =u_{tt}

Comment: can somebody help me solve u_{xx}=u_{tt}